# jQuery - Replace Image With Another After Certain Number of Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

-- *I'm new to jQuery disclaimer* --

I have two images:

```
https://i.imgur.com/l2H17fn.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/5nlOoyc.jpg
```

I'd like to show the second one in place of the first one after it's been clicked on *five* times.

To get the image to replace after one click, I have this:

HTML:

```
<div class = "dog">
<img id="happy" src="https://i.imgur.com/l2H17fn.jpg">
</div>
```

jQUERY:

```
$('.dog').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   $("#happy").attr('src',"https://i.imgur.com/5nlOoyc.jpg");
   return false;
 });
```

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/HappyHands31/pen/pmPREJ).

Now what if I want to replace the image after the fifth click? What would that look like?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is a pretty simple issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of clicks with a variable:

```js
// initialize click count to zero.
var clicks = 0;

$('.dog').on('click', function() {

  // increment click count.
  clicks++;

  // FOR DEMO - output the click count to the console.
  // console.log(clicks);

  // if clicks is greater than or equal to 5...
  if (clicks >= 5) {

    // ... change the image ...
    $("#happy").attr('src', "https://i.imgur.com/5nlOoyc.jpg");

    // .. and remove this click handler.
    $(this).off('click');

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dog">
  <img id="happy" src="https://i.imgur.com/l2H17fn.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: So basically the clicks variable increases (by 1) every time the function runs, and the function runs every time the `dog` div is clicked on - that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...I think the trick is to have a global semaphore variable...This one toggles between though...:)

```js
var clicks = 0;

$('.dog').on('click', function(e){
  clicks++;
  
  if(clicks >= 5){
    if($('#happy').attr('src') !== 'https://i.imgur.com/5nlOoyc.jpg'){
      $("#happy").attr('src',"https://i.imgur.com/5nlOoyc.jpg");
    }else{
      $("#happy").attr('src',"https://i.imgur.com/l2H17fn.jpg");
    }
    clicks = 0;
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "dog">
  <img id="happy" src="https://i.imgur.com/l2H17fn.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Just for fun, I'm actually trying to make it toggle between happy and sad on _every_ click now, though I know that wasn't my original question.

Comment: cool cool, i guess you could mess around with the condition on number of clicks in that case.